# Need to get a site redirecting both to www and https

Tags: redirect, iis, url-rewriting, asp-classic, web-config

Parts of other answers on Stack Overflow worked, other parts didn't, so I thought I would ask for the full solution including IIS settings re bindings.

I have a site (old ASP classic) that is being moved to IIS 8 (2012).

The site works when testing it from my hosts file.

At the moment I can only get it to redirect http to https not non www requests to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) as well.

So I have 2 bindings in IIS (80/433) for [www.example.com](http://www.example.com), I also tried it with another set without the www. e.g example.com but then I got errors such as the system is trying to process your request in such a way it won't return e.g following redirects around in a circle etc.

I am not so sure if that was about the 2 lots of bindings or the rules it was getting a bit messy then. So I need the whole approach from IIS binding setup and web.config rules (or is there a better way in IIS 8 to force all 80 traffic to port 443?)

I already have a number of ISAPI rules in my web.config file such as

```html
<rule name="Order" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^applications/order/?$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="plugins/order.asp" />
</rule>
<rule name="Robots 1" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^robotstxt\.asp$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="robottxt.asp" />
</rule>
<rule name="Robots 2" stopProcessing="false">
    <match url="^robotstxt$" />
    <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false" />
    <action type="Rewrite" url="robottxt.asp" />
</rule>
```

So when I read up I saw about people trying to to do both rules at once or in two sets but it just never managed to work foe me.

I need non http requests to go to https
and for non www requests to go to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) e.g https://www.example.com

At the moment it's partially working but only because I am not trying the non www. redirects.

I have 2 bindings for the [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) hostnames and this one rule at the top.

```html
<rule name="Redirect to HTTPS" stopProcessing="true">
  <match url="(.*)" />
  <conditions logicalGrouping="MatchAll" trackAllCaptures="false">
    <add input="{HTTPS}" pattern="^OFF$" />
  </conditions>
  <action type="Redirect" url="https://{HTTP_HOST}/{R:1}" redirectType="SeeOther" />
</rule>
```

So all the rules are working including the http to https. However I need non www rules to work as well.

To get it to keep the rest of my rules AND to get it to ALSO redirect non www. traffic to [www.example.com](http://www.example.com) e.g https://www.example.com. What is the best way to do this.

1. Do I need another pair of bindings set up without www. e.s example.com for 80/443?
2. Then, what rules do I add in and what order do they need to be as int .htacces they are processed top to bottom in loops an I just wonder with IIS way there is also a logical path that could trip it over causing infinite loops.

Comment: Are you sure that there isnt any redirecting happening in the coding of the site itself? Possibly an include on every page.

Comment: nope, there are no redirects on the pages at all. I have a binding for https/http for both www.domain.com and domain.com. There is nothing else happening in the site.

Comment: ok, I dont have much experience with bindings but as a workaround you could include a coded redirect on each page. Either add an include into the top of each page or add a bit of code to an existing include (as long as  it is included before any html is sent to the browser)

Comment: Sounds like a big job. I've noticed however its ONLY when urls are entered with a page URL after the end that they are not redirected e.g example.com will get redirected to https://www.example.com but if I enter example.com/applications/order (another redirect rule in the file which takes you to /applications/order.aspx) then it doesn't work. So maybe its something in the core rule for www/https that just doesn't handle page URLS at the end of it ?

Answer (score 0):

I think adding the include is what I would do if you needed to get on top of this very quickly. Use a search and replace program to add the include tag into all of your pages:

```
<!--#include file="redirect.asp"-->
```

Then create the "redirect.asp" with something similar to below:

```
<%
webDomain=LCase(Request.ServerVariables("HTTP_HOST"))
scriptname=Request.ServerVariables("SCRIPT_NAME")
If InStr(webDomain,"https://www.example.com")=0 Then

    Response.Status="301 Moved Permanently"
    Response.AddHeader "Location", "https://www.example.com" & scriptname

End If
%>
```

You may need to tweak that a bit but its the basics of a coded redirect anyway.